# Does humidity relate to static sensitive?

Tags: antistatic, humidity, static

Are components more static-sensitive in drier places or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not that they are more sensitive, but that the static builds up on you, and your parts more quickly and readily, thus making it easier to fry something in a drier environment.

Edit: The dry(er) air also makes it easier to discharge the static onto whatever you are working on.

Answer (score 3):

Components tend to be more prone to damage from electro-static discharge in dryer environments, because the less humidity there is in the air, the less conductive air and other materials are. This allows static charge (charge imbalances) to build up more easily than in more conductive environments. This extra charge imbalance makes electro-static discharge more likely, although (to answer the original question) the components themselves are not technically any more static sensitive than before.